# Overflow-y phantom margin in chrome Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, scrollbar, overflow

i have a curious problem with overflow: auto in chrome. There is a panel with `position: fixed; height: 100%; min-width: 250px; right: 0; top: 0; overflow-y: auto;` and when the scrollbar appear, inner elements are rendered with offset, but reacting as in correct position (even console highlights them correct). How to fix that? Thank you

[image: No overflow]

[image: With overflow]

[image: Console]

[image: Hover sample]

Comment: Could you please provide a live example reproducing the problem?

Comment: Things like this its good to see a working version so we can mess around with the code and come up with answers

Comment: Looks like it is because of box-shadow property... https://jsfiddle.net/jwx7Lrph/

Answer (score 0):

Your *a* tags contain some white spaces - have you checked that?

Comment: White spaces makes no difference :/

Answer (score 0):

The `box-shadow property` on fixed block with overflow caused this behaviour. A solution is do wrap content which overflows to another container and let main block be overflow: visible. [Sample solution here](https://jsfiddle.net/psxafgjg/1).

So this seems like a Chrome bug, because other browsers don't suffer from this problem.